# Как удалять файлы в Linux с возможностью восстановления?

Tags: linux

Как сделать так чтобы команда `rm` по умолчанию удаляла файлы в корзину?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если пользоваться десктопной корзиной, то удалить файл в неё можно командой `gvfs-trash`. Присутствует почти во всех десктопах.

Установить:

```
apt install gvfs-bin
```

Удалить:

```
gvfs-trash ./имяфайла
```

При удалении создается папка `.Trash` на текущем разделе [согласно спецификации](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec/) .

Команда `trash` имеет большие возможности по сравнению с `gvfs-trash`.

Установить:

```
apt install trash-cli
```

Удалить файл командой просто `trash`. Другие команды `trash-empty`,  `trash-list`,   `trash-put`,    `trash-rm` (удаляет файл из корзины).

```
trash --help
Usage: trash [OPTION]... FILE...

Put files in trash

Options:
  --version            show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -d, --directory      ignored (for GNU rm compatibility)
  -f, --force          ignored (for GNU rm compatibility)
  -i, --interactive    ignored (for GNU rm compatibility)
  -r, -R, --recursive  ignored (for GNU rm compatibility)
  -v, --verbose        explain what is being done

To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo',
use one of these commands:

    trash -- -foo

    trash ./-foo
```

Утилиту `trash` можно повесить как алиас на `rm`.

```
alias rm=trash
rm -v Загрузки/Calendar\ \(1\).ics                                                               
  trash: Volume of file: /
  trash: Trash-dir: /home/eri/.local/share/Trash from volume: /
  trash: 'Загрузки/Calendar (1).ics' trashed in ~/.local/share/Trash
```

Пример использования (удалить,просмотреть список, восстановить):

```
$ trash Загрузки/Calendar.ics 
$ trash-list 
2017-10-24 14:44:49 /home/eri/Загрузки/Calendar.ics

$ trash-restore                                                                                   
   0 2017-10-24 14:44:49 /home/eri/Загрузки/Calendar.ics
What file to restore [0..0]: 0
```

Обе утилиты совместимы с десктопом и удаленные файлы отобразятся в "Корзине".

Comment: 9 лет линуксом пользуюсь, тока щас узнал про возможность удаления в корзину из консоли. Афигеть.

Comment: Место освобождается при использовании этой команды? Или корзина тоже занимает место как в винде?

Comment: как в винде. перекладывается в папку Trash на этом же диске